# why is representation type for chrono::nanoseconds a signed integer type?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

In gcc 4.84 in file /usr/include/c++/4.8 we have

```
namespace std  
{
   typedef duration<int64_t, nano>     nanoseconds;
```

Why is the representation type for nanosecond a signed integer type? Why isn't it unsigned? when can we have a duration object with a negative value ?

Comment: When you subtract a time point from one in its past.

Comment: Maybe negative duration can represent `before` from some timepoint.

Answer (score 9):

> when can we have a duration object with a negative value ?

Any time you want to represent a negative duration!

e.g. "Ten seconds earlier" would be `std::chrono::seconds(-10)` and if you add that to some `time_point t` then you get a `time_point`  that is ten seconds before `t`.

The standard says "A `duration` type measures time between two points in time (`time_points`)." It doesn't say that it can only measure time between non-decreasing time points. So that means it can be used to measure the time between `t1` and `t2` even if `t2 < t1`. And to do that simply, you need a negative value.

If durations couldn't be signed then, to represent an offset that means "earlier" not "later", you'd have to use something like `std::pair<bool, duration>` where the `bool` says whether it's a positive or negative offset, and then you'd have to do:

```
chrono::time_point adjust(chrono::time_point t, pair<bool, duration> offset)
{
  if (offset.first)  // positive
    return t + offset.second;
  else // negative
    return t - offset.second;
}
```

This is dumb. The language and the hardware already support this far more expressively and efficiently, by using signed integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If two objects `a` and `b` are defined such that `a - b` is a duration, then it's desirable to have `a - b = -(b - a)`.

To implement that anti-commutative property, the duration needs to be signed.

Answer (score 4):

It is not just gcc implementation, it is required by the standard ([time.syn]):

```
typedef duration<signed integer type of at least 64 bits,        nano> nanoseconds;
```

A duration represents a time difference between two time points A and B. If A > B, the duration is positive, otherwise it's negative, so it makes perfect sense.